# Centered row of letters

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to make a centered row of letters, each with their own element. For example, I want to make this:

```
<div className="active__header">
  <h3 className="header__letter">H</h3>
  <h3 className="header__letter">E</h3>
  <h3 className="header__letter">L</h3>
  <h3 className="header__letter">L</h3>
  <h3 className="header__letter">O</h3>
</div>
```

Look as if it were just:

```
<h3>HELLO</h3>
```

I tried using `float: left` on all the letters, which brought them all on the same line, but `text-align: center` wouldn't work, so the letters were not centered.

Comment: `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: There is no `className` attribute, change it to `class`.

You can change the `display` of the `h3` from the default `block` to `inline` and that will allow you to use `text-align: center`:

```css
.active__header {
  text-align: center;
}

.header__letter {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="active__header">
  <h3 class="header__letter">H</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">E</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">L</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">L</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">O</h3>
</div>
```

The only problem with this approach is that with `inline`, the whitespace matters and is converted to a single space, so you will see one-space gaps between your letters. If you want to remove it, then remove the whitespace between your `h3` tags. There are several ways to do that, one of which is to break the lines inside the tags:

```css
.active__header {
  text-align: center;
}

.header__letter {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="active__header">
  <h3 class="header__letter">H</h3><h3
      class="header__letter">E</h3><h3
      class="header__letter">L</h3><h3
      class="header__letter">L</h3><h3
      class="header__letter">O</h3>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use flex box:

```css
.active__header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="active__header">
  <h3 class="header__letter">H</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">E</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">L</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">L</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">O</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I used className because I am using react.js

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead, then you can use `text-align:center;` to `.active__header`.

One more thing, I changed `className` to `class`

```css
.active__header {
  text-align:center;
}

.header__letter {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="active__header">
  <h3 class="header__letter">H</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">E</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">L</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">L</h3>
  <h3 class="header__letter">O</h3>
</div>
```